# Pushing a value in array does not display in View angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to display the incorrect answers made by the user on a specific quiz. But it does not display the data in my HTML. What am I doing wrong in here?

on my html:

```
 <ion-slide *ngFor="let incorrect of wrongAnswers;let i=index">
  <ion-label>{{i+1}}</ion-label>
  <h5>{{incorrect.questionA}}</h5>
  <h5>{{incorrect.choice}}</h5>
  <h5>{{incorrect.answer}}</h5>
  <button ion-button (click)="error()"></button>
</ion-slide>
```

on my typescript:

```
 wrongAnswers: any[] = [];


 if (answer.correct == false) {
  this.wrongAnswers.push([{
    questionA: question.questionText,
    choice: answer.selected,
    answer: answer.answer
  }]);
}
```

On my console this is what is being displayed:

[image]

Comment: Try removing the `[]` that surround the objects you're pushing, i.e. `.push({ ... });`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to push **`array`** to already existing array, if you really want to do that use **[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** instead

```
this.wrongAnswers.concat([{
    questionA: question.questionText,
    choice: answer.selected,
    answer: answer.answer
  }]);
```

if you want to push one object, remove the **`[]`** , so that object will be pushed

```
this.wrongAnswers.push({
    questionA: question.questionText,
    choice: answer.selected,
    answer: answer.answer
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The array reference isn't changing when using `Array.prototype.push`, therefore the angular changedetection isn't aware of the changes.

And also you were pushing an array into you array not a simple object.

Use `Array.prototype.concat` to create a new reference when adding an item to the array:

```
this.wrongAnswers = this.wrongAnswers.concat({
  questionA: question.questionText,
  choice: answer.selected,
  answer: answer.answer
});
```